# Error in arrays output compared to input

Tags: java

I have the code below, where the user has to input 5 values in an array, and print out the same.

```
package Arrays;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int size=5;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the 5 number you want to be stored in an array");
        int a[] =new int[size];
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            a[i]=input.nextInt();
        }           
        displayArray(a);
        sumOfArray();
        productOfArray();
        smallAndLargeOfArray();
        averageOfArray();
    }

    private static void displayArray(int arr[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i] + ' ');
        }
    }
}
```

here is my input:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

and the output that I'm getting is:

```
33
34
35
36
37
```

Please let me know where I'm going wrong and how can I fix this.

Comment: Remember that a `char` in java is really just an integer. When you write `arr[i] + ' '` you are actually adding 2 numbers, not concatenating 2 strings.

Comment: In other words: change `+ ' '` to `+ " "`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
System.out.println(arr[i] + ' ');
```

to

```
System.out.println(arr[i]);
```

or

```
System.out.println(arr[i] + " ");
```

When you are printing `arr[i] + ' '`, first the expression is evaluated as the addition of an `int` and a `char` (the integral value of the space character, which is 32), and only then the resulting integer is printed. Therefore, all the integers in your array are offset by 32 when printed this way.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination

Answer (score 2):

`' '` has ascii code 32. When you use `arr[i] + ' '` you convert second operand to integer and add to first operand.

Answer (score 1):

In ASCII `space` has a char value of 32 (decimal) and char is actually an integer value. It gets added to your int value and gives that output.

`System.out.println(arr[i]);`

and

`System.out.println(arr[i]+" ");`

will solve the issue.